# How can I make a function return true after functions within jQuery's .each() finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, each

I'm using knockout.js. I have several editable grids in a form, and the names of the fields inside those grids matter, so using `uniqueName` isn't an option.

So what I'm doing is calling a function to rename the fields when the user clicks submit.

```
function renameFields(o, index) {
  var el_name    = $(o).attr('name');
  var name_index = el_name.lastIndexOf('_') + 1;

  $(o).attr('name', el_name.substring(0, name_index) + index);
}

function Submit() {
  self.submit = function() {
    // Use unique AND meaningful input/textarea [name]s in .grids.
    window.index_arr = [];

    $('.grid').each(function() {
      $(this)
      .children('.row')
      .each(function(i){
        window.index_arr.push(i);

        $(this)
        .find('input, textarea')
        .each(function() {
          renameFields($(this), window.index_arr[i]);
        })
      })
    });

    // Submit the form
    return true;
  }
}
```

`renameFields` works fine, but `true` is returned before it's called on every field.

Comment: It **is** called when the user clicks submit.

Comment: @Nix @ColBeseder It's not a typo. I just didn't include the html that shows the binding, because I know that's not where the problem lies. The function is being called and it's returning `true` before it finishes renaming the fields. Did you read the whole post?

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but have you thought about binding the `name` properties so KO keeps them up to date?

Comment: @johnnycardy I haven't. I'm new to KO and didn't know it was possible. I'm guessing that would be something like `attr: { name: 'whatever_' + var.length }`, is that right?

Comment: @curtisblackwell yeah, that's right syntax for binding the attribute. I'll create an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Knockout do the dirty work of keeping the indices of your attributes up to date with something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="grid" class="grid">
    <div class="row" data-bind="foreach:rows">
        <input data-bind="attr: { name: 'string_' + $index() }">
        <textarea data-bind="attr: { name: 'string_' + $index() }">
    </div>
</div>
```

View model:

```
var vm = {
    rows: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("grid"));
```

Comment: when appending `$index` to a string as the `name`, `$index` returns a function instead of the index itself. See http://jsfiddle.net/curtisblackwell/Gafqz/. If you remove `'test_' +`, it works fine.

Comment: ah, duh. just need to add `()` to index.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us more about how you are setting up the click handlers...

I'll take a SWAG at it... I think you are dealing with [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Without a fiddle I can't test it, but try the following code.

```
var renameFields = function(o, index) {
  var el_name    = $(o).attr('name');
  var name_index = el_name.lastIndexOf('_') + 1;

  $(o).attr('name', el_name.substring(0, name_index) + index);
}

var Submit = function() {
  self.submit = function() {
    // Use unique AND meaningful input/textarea [name]s in .grids.
    window.index_arr = [];

    $('.grid').each(function() {
      $(this)
      .children('.row')
      .each(function(i){
        window.index_arr.push(i);

        $(this)
        .find('input, textarea')
        .each(function() {
          renameFields($(this), window.index_arr[i]);
        })
      })
    });

    // Submit the form
    return true;
  }
}
```